# Onclick button, replace all numbers [0-9] with -- javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a counter.Ιf you press play counts from 0 to 9.
I want a button that turns off the count, and instead of (0-9) displays (--). If you press it again to activate the count again etc..

I have found this so far. When I press the button it turns to --, but when the counter goes to 2,  it writes numbers again (2 3 etc).
I know it sounds easy but I wanted your valuable help. Thanks

HTML

```
    <button id="numbers" onclick="changetoText();">--</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function changetoText() {
numbers.innerHTML = numbers.innerHTML.replace(/1/g, "--");
numbers.innerHTML = numbers.innerHTML.replace(/2/g, "--");
```

etc..

Comment: The regexp pattern `\d` matches any digit. You don't need to repeat it for every number.

Comment: Hi, can you write the whole line in javascript to understand it? Also, when the counter is playing, the numbers continue to count 2-3-4-5.. They are not replaced by (-). Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to use `.replace` at all? Just use `numbers.innerHTML = '--'`

Comment: If you're using an interval timer to increment the counter, you need to stop it when they click the button.

Comment: I did it, but it only changes the specific number (i.e "1") when I click the button. Then it counts and displays 3-4-5-6 etc.

Comment: I do not want to stop the counter, because in every count there is a drum sound , so if it is possible to find a solution while the counter is playing.. thanks....

Comment: You said "I want a button that turns off the count".

Comment: Yes the counting of numbers. This does not mean that the play button must be deactivated.

Comment: The function that increments the counter can check if it contains `--`. If so, it doesn't need to increment it. Then when you start the counter again, put `0` in there and the increment function will start counting again.

Comment: No it's like this:  if (currentStep == "1") {
document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = "1";
}
if(currentStep == "2") {
document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = "2";
} etc

Comment: Why not just `.innerHTML = currentStep;`?

Comment: That's the counter, not the function for stopping the counter.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setInterval function to run code every X milliseconds. In this case, you want to increase the number in every tick. The clearInterval function cancels the interval you set.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#numbers");

let number = 0;
let paused = false;
let numbersInterval;

function toggleCounting() {
  if (isCounting()) {
    pause();
  } else {
    count();
  }
}

function isCounting() {
  return /\d/g.test(button.innerHTML);
}

function count() {
  paused = false;
  numbersInterval = setInterval(every1Second, 1000);
}

function every1Second() {
  if (!paused && number < 9) {
    button.innerHTML = ++number;
  } else {
    clearInterval(numbersInterval);
    if (number === 9) {
      reset();
    }
  }
}

function pause() {
  paused = true;
  clearInterval(numbersInterval);
  button.innerHTML = "--";
}

function reset() {
  button.innerHTML = "Play";
  number = 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="numbers" onclick="toggleCounting()">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it reads innerHTML in every "currentStep".
Try with condition if /else. For example, **if** it plays show me the innerHTML "1-9" , **else** if I click the button, show me "--" for the whole pattern.

```
    function changetoText(text) {
  var x = document.getElementById("numbers");
  if (x.innerHTML === "--") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "--";
  }
}
```

Comment: Great.. but how am I suppose to write all that? I tried this but it works only for 1 number.  then it returns to (--).  numbers.innerHTML = numbers.innerHTML.replace(/1/g, "--"); Any idea?? Thanks..